# 400 Bad Request: invalid header name with curl POST request

Tags: curl, http-headers, http-post

I am trying to make a post request to an elastic search endpoint.
The api key is correct and I was taking reference from this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-api-key.html
for the api key format.
my curl request

```
curl -H "Authorization:ApiKey xxxxx" 
\ -H "Content-Type:application/x-ndjson 
-XPOST "https://712bbxxx/tttt/_bulk" 
--data-binary "@sss.json"
```

the error message:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
400 Bad Request: invalid header name
```

I am pretty sure the quotes symbol & the spacing should be correct. may I ask if you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Is it because you forgot to close the quotes after `-H "Content-Type:application/x-ndjson`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to close quotes for the content-type header, try

```
-H "Content-Type:application/x-ndjson"
```